# wgetでサーバにおいたdmgを取得できない

Tags: macos

自分の管理しているサーバにdmgをscpして、それをwgetでダウンロードできません。
具体的には以下のようなエラーが出力されます。

% wget https://◯◯◯/◯◯.app
--2017-03-15 03:03:18--  https://◯◯◯/◯◯.app
~~~
HTTP による接続要求を送信しました、応答を待っています... 403 Forbidden
2017-03-15 03:03:19 エラー 403: Forbidden。

permissionの問題かと思ったのですが、当ファイルの権限は777でした。。
調べても解決方法がわかりません。どなたか宜しくお願いします。

Comment: サーバー側のログは見てないの？

Comment: `--secure-protocol=auto`オプションをつけるとどうなりますか？

Comment: もう少し具体的な情報があるとトラブルシューティングのお手伝いが出来るかもしれません。1. サーバー環境(OS,Apacheサーバソフト名)について 2. サーバーのログ 3. dmg を scp したアップロード先のディレクトリ情報、パーミッション 4. `権限は777` と書かれている内容について具体的に `ls -l` などの結果を書いて欲しい。5. dmg を scp してるのに .app をダウンロードしてる理由。

Answer (score 3):

#### HTTPSに制限している場合

`--secure-protocol=auto`オプションを追加してください。

`wget`コマンドでHTTPSプロトコルを使ってファイルをやり取りするには `--secure-protocol=<protocol>` オプションを指定する方法があります。GNU Wget 1.18では`<protocol>`に

- `auto`：自動指定
- `SSLv2`, `SSLv3`, `TLSv1`, `TLSv1_1`, `TLSv1_2`：各プロトコルを使用（古いサーバー向け）
- `PFS`：Perfect Forward Securityな暗号スイートを使用したTLS

を指定できますが、基本的には `--secure-protocol=auto` で上手くいくかと思います。詳しくは[GNU Wgetのマニュアル](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#HTTPS-_0028SSL_002fTLS_0029-Options)をご覧ください。このマニュアルを見ると他にもHTTPSの詳しい事情に対応するためのオプションが存在しますが、この回答では割愛します（参考に挙げているURLを参照ください）。

また、今回は大丈夫でしょうが、SSLサポート無しにコンパイルされた`wget`だとこれらのオプションに対応していません。その場合は自分でコンパイルする等が必要です。

- 参考

  - [GNU Wget Manual - HTTPS (SSL/TLS) Options](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#HTTPS-_0028SSL_002fTLS_0029-Options)
  - ["Error while downloading HTTPS files using wget"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/338869/error-while-downloading-https-files-using-wget) -- Ask Ubuntu

---

#### サーバー側でリクエストを制限している場合

HTTPのレベルにおいてサーバー側で何かしら制限をかけている場合も`wget`で 403 Forbidden が出ることがあります。たとえば典型的には User-Agent で弾かれていることがあります（GNU Wgetのデフォルトの User-Agent は`Wget/VERSION`です）。この場合、これらを逐一設定する必要があります。

`wget --help`や`man wget`を参考にしつつ、`--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0"`などのオプションを追加してください。User-Agent の他に考えられるものとしては、リファラやメディアタイプなどがあります。`--referer`や`--header`あたりを探してください。また、robots.txtやHTMLのmetaタグなどでアクセス制御されている場合もあります。リンクしたGNU Wgetのマニュアルをご覧ください。

ご自分で管理されているサーバーなのでしたらサーバーログを見つつサーバーの設定を変えるなり設定に合わせて`wget`するなりできると思います。

- 参考

  - ["Sites not accepting wget user agent header"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182553/sites-not-accepting-wget-user-agent-header) -- Stack Overflow
  - ["wget not working"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058811/wget-not-working) -- Stack Overflow
  - [GNU Wget Manual - HTTP Options](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#HTTP-Options)
  - [GNU Wget Manual - Robot Exclusion](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Robot-Exclusion.html)